# Opening a page in a second project in a Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Sorry for my ignorance, I would like to ask the following: I have a Visual Studio 2008 solution that has 2 projects (a 'Web Site project' and a second one is a 'Web Application project'.

When I run the solution in Visual Studio, the first projects starts and I can see an ASP web page (in run-time). When I click a button on this page I would like to run a procedure that belongs to the second project, pass some parameters and start the second project in run-time as well.

I cannot figure out how to reference from "Project1", any  files, procedures, etc that belong to "Project2" in the solution.

Thank you,

M.R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right Click Project1->Add Reference and then make a reference to your project 2.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on References->Add a Reference,t hen select the Project tab and pick the project you want to reference.